# How to check next page button is available or not using python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want scrap some events data from page then enter next page scrap the event data  then next page, same process until next page button is not available. the question is how to implement in if..else condition once the button is not available.

**Condition code**

```
while True:
  for i in range(len(links)):
    scrapy()

  if #Write Condition to Check if Next page button is available : 
      driver.get('website_link_here')
      next_page= '//*[@class="pagination"]/span[7]/a'
      link = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=160).until(lambda d: d.find_element(By.XPATH,next_page))
      driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", link)
      scrapy()
  else:
      break

driver.quit()
```

**Scrapy() function code**

```
def scrapy():
    selector = '.event-poster'
    event_name = '.col-md-12 h1'
    links = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=500).until(lambda d: d.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,selector))
    links[i].click()
    name_e = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=500).until(lambda d: d.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,event_name))
    print(name_e.text)
    driver.back()
```

**Libraries and driver**

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
#import time
#import csv
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
selector = '.event-poster'
driver.get('website_link_here')
links = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=500).until(lambda d: d.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,selector))
```

Comment: There must be a `class` or `id` for that element

Comment: `next_page= "//*[@class="pagination"]/span[7]/a"` is the XPath of the next page(that element) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sorry, I do some mistakes in the previous code but now after 2 days I edit and change some logic now this code is working as you want. Also If you want some explanation on how this code works, then let me know in the comments then I will add that in my post too.**

Update code. import this too `from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException`

```
i = 0
while True:
  for i in range(len(links)):
    scrapy()

  try:
    driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'next')
    i+=1
  except NoSuchElementException:
    break
  else:
    links = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=500).until(lambda d: d.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,selector))
    driver.get(f'https://shoobs.com/find-events?page={i}')
```

You can scroll down to the page using this command `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")`

##### Here is your full update code.

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
#import time
#import csv
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException



driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
selector = '.event-poster'
driver.get('https://shoobs.com/find-events')
links = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=500).until(lambda d: d.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,selector))

def scrapy():
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    selector = '.event-poster'
    event_name = '.col-md-12 h1'
    links = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=500).until(lambda d: d.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,selector))
    links[i].click()
    name_e = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=500).until(lambda d: d.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,event_name))
    print(name_e.text)
    driver.back()

i = 0
while True:
  for i in range(len(links)):
    scrapy()

  try:
    driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'next')
    i+=1
  except NoSuchElementException:
    break
  else:
    links = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=500).until(lambda d: d.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,selector))
    driver.get(f'https://shoobs.com/find-events?page={i}')

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you @codester_09 it worked for me. but a new issue raised once the browser opens if i scroll browser it will go through each events and work properly  and extract data but if i don't scroll and put  as its it gives error. what is the issue I am confused.

Comment: @Saifu I have edited my code Now it's working, I Hope this is helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248170/discussion-between-saifu-and-codester-09).

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
    
try:
    nextpagebutton = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, buttonxpath)))
except TimeoutException:
    print("No button available")
```